# Sphinx classes not found despite library being in classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, sphinx4

I downloaded [sphinx4-1.0beta6-bin.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/1.0%20beta6/) and installed it on my 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I was able to run the `HelloWorld` example. However, when I create my own class and create a `Configuration` object as shown here:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

It gets flagged as an error. **Eclipse** cannot find the class at all even though I have appropriate jars in the library and library is in the build path.

Here are the jars in the library:

1. `js.jar`
2. `jsapi.jar`
3. `sphinx4.jar`
4. `tags.jar`

Then, why am I getting this error ?

Comment: did you clean and build your workspace?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Yes, it gives me other suggestions like from `edu.cmu.sphinx.props` package. It points to `Configurable`

Comment: hmm can you show the smallest possible class with imports?

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/Configurable.html is that what you want?  Because this is an interface.

Comment: @Woot4Moo That is NOT what I want. I copied the example from CMU's website and I wanna run that. However, I cannot. http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Comment: i am looking at the API http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/ and that class doesnt exist.

Comment: haa ? I copied it from their site, bro. Check the link.

Comment: it doesn't really matter if you copied it from their site or not, I am telling you that is their API documentation.

Comment: awh..... so how do i learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class doesn't exist in released version, to use it you need to checkout an experimental hl-interface branch with subversion:

http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/code/HEAD/tree/branches/hl-interface/

To learn more about subversion see

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-subversion/

Comment: ok so if I want to learn the released version, what do I do ?

Comment: read the documentation included, run the demos, study their code.

Comment: Ok, doing that. In the current version everything has to be configured in XML correct ?